# A few C++ inheritance questions in practice on my example?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I know all the theory of OOP but there are some things which I can't understand. Suppose, I have a vector3D class which has 3 variable (3 coordinates ) and some operations like calculating the length and stuff.

Now I want to build a vector2D class which will inherit from Vector3D , after all it's all the same just with the third coordinate being equal to 0, now how do I do that? how do I write the constructor of Vector2D which will build a vector3D with the third coordinate equal to 0?

If I make the coordinates private how do I inherit them and use them as coordinates of the Vector2D, or even if I make them protected will that mean that vector2D will have it's own separate coordinates?

Comment: Inheritance models an "is-a" relationships (e.g a dog "is-a" animal). Are all 2D vectors also 3D vectors?

Comment: `I know *all* the theory of OOP` Very funny.

Comment: Usually that's not done using inheritance, and especially not in a _reverse_ manner. That's a call for templates.

Comment: How to write the constructor: Google. How to do it with private: Don´t use private. And protected doesn´t duplicate variables.

Comment: You need to read up more on how to use OOP, if you're saying you know it all, and are then trying that problem. Although, yes, you can do it that way, you should really inherit 3D from 2D. It makes very little sense to go the other way around.

Comment: While I agree that the way to go is to inherit 3D from 2D, I can see where this guy is coming from mathematically. All 2D vectors *are* 3D vectors, if you think about it.

Comment: @Ludwik 3D is a special case of 2D. Otherwise, by well-ordering, you can say that 2D is a special case of 3D, but that means 1D is a special case of 2D, but that means 0D is a special case of 1D; that's not correct. The order is from smallest to largest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will achieve what you are describing:

```cpp
class Vector3D {
public:
    Vector3D(int x, int y, int z) : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) { }
    virtual ~Vector3D() = default;
    int get_x() { return x_; }
    int get_y() { return y_; }
    int get_z() { return z_; }
    // ... other member functions ...
private:
    int x_, y_, z_;
};

class Vector2D : public Vector3D {
public:
    Vector2D(int x, int y) : Vector3D(x, y, 0) { }
    virtual ~Vector2D() = default;
};
```

All member functions defined in Vector3D will be available to an object of type Vector2D. This also means that, in this implementation, you could call `get_z()` on an object of type Vector2D.

```cpp
Vector2D v2d(5, 7);
int z = v2d.get_z(); // z will be 0
```

This is probably not what you want. If it is what you want, great! But also consider this:

```cpp
Vector3D* ptr = new Vector2D(8, 3);
```

That code is legal, do you also want to allow that to happen?

By the way, inheriting Vector2D from Vector3D is required if you want Vector2D objects to behave like Vector3D objects:

```cpp
#include <vector>
std::vector<Vector3D*> v;
v.push_back(new Vector3D(1, 2, 3));
v.push_back(new Vector2D(4, 5)); // Legal because Vector2D inherits from Vector3D

v[0]->get_z(); // = 3
v[1]->get_z(); // = 0
```

**Sidenote:** never use raw pointers in production code, use `std::shared_ptr<Vector3D>` instead!!

If this implementation is good depends on your needs and is for you to decide. It has both advantages and disadvantages.

---

To answer your other questions:

> How do I write the constructor of Vector2D which will build a vector3D with the third coordinate equal to zero?

You need to use [initialization lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to call a certain constructor from a base class:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base(int i) {
        std::cout << "Base ctor with " << i << "\n";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int i, int j) : Base(i) { // Calls Base's constructor with argument 'i'
        std::cout << "Derived ctor with " << i << " and " << j << "\n"; 
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Derived d(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ Base ctor with 1
$ Derived ctor with 1 and 2
```

Initializing objects inside an initialization list will make sure their respective constructors get called first.

---

> If I make the coordinates private how do I inherit them and use them as coordinates of the Vector2D, or even if I make them protected will that mean that vector2D will have it's own separate coordinates?

`private` members are only accessible from within the class itself. To allow a derived class to access them, you need to make them `protected` (or `public`, but that will make it accessible by everyone!).

```cpp
class Base {
protected:
    int touch_me;
private:
    int cant_touch_me;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void foo() {
        int touch_me = 0; // Legal.
        int cant_touch_me = 1; // Illegal, will result in a compile error.
    }
private:
    int lonely;
};
```

All objects of type Base will have two data members: `touch_me` and `cant_touch_me`.

All objects of type Derived will have three data members: `touch_me`, `cant_touch_me` and `lonely`. Functions declared and implemented by Derived will only be able to access `touch_me` and `lonely`, but the object does contain all three!

Comment: A 2-d vector *can* have a `z` dimension; it is generally zero, sometimes constant.

Comment: @DonLarynx I assumed the OP didn't want a Vector2D to have an accessible thrid dimension. I've corrected my answer.